# Can I submit questions via SMS?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is there any way I can text a question using SMS texting to Stack Overflow? For example I text "How do static classes work" to some number using my number linked in to my SO account?

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?

Comment: Probably because some folks disagree that this would be a useful feature. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) for details on voting on meta.

Comment: I could have sworn this was already a feature.

Comment: Bill, via StackApps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice idea, but it's not available right now on StackExchange.

Possible reasoning:

- It costs moneyz!
- You can't directly see the question you're answering.
- You don't get much feedback (unless you want to spend moar moneyz!).

As far as I know, the only way to add answers from mobile is via the web browser and the mobile site.

Comment: If the question is posted like any other question then someone can see the question your answering.

Comment: @ChrisOkyen: Downvotes on [meta] indicate disagreement (not unusefulness), the community simply doesn't agree with you on that subject. Also, if you're writing SMS, how can you tell if the question you're answering wasn't changed in the middle? That's what I meant by "you can't see the question directly"

Comment: Oh Ok. Gotcha I just meant using the SMS from the asking point not the answering. But I see what you mean thanks @Truth

Comment: I still think despite what the other 15 people think on SO that it would be usefull to people who don't want the distraction of internet on there phone or have have to pay for the data plan that both come with smart phones.

Answer (score 15):

Other than helping kids cheat on tests, I'm not sure what the use case is for this. There's no way people are going to adequately describe their question in a text message. I'm not totally sure you *could* ask a worthwhile question in a text message. Your example is case in point--that would get closed as Not a Real Question due to being too broad and vague.

Comment: Yeah, that's gotta be the biggest issue with this. You can (usually) barely write a good title in 160 characters, nevermind a whole question. (Although I guess you could send multiple messages, but that would introduce another set of potential problems.)

Comment: @Brad Mace Besides feciously commenting about the downfall of it ( kids cheating on tests ), which i do not appreciate, I agree with you 100% about it being hard to text a good question via SMS texting. The example was just that, there was no examination necessary at the question itself necessary so I don't know why you did so. But I will upvote you for the positive remarks as soon as I get >= 15 points. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chris I wasn't accusing you of anything, that's just the only demographic I could imagine using this in large numbers.

Comment: Oh gotcha not a lot of grandma's on SO programming apps that automatically design kniting patterns huh ;) Let me know anyone if you are out there.